# How to make the image in Unity the same as in MagicaVoxel?

Tags: unity, magicavoxel

I've seen a similar question before, but this question was asked 5 years ago and a lot of things in Unity have changed.

Here is the result I would like to achieve
[image]

But what happened in Unity[image]

How can I achieve the same result, or as similar as possible?

Comment: The only differences I see here are the background image / skybox, the position of the gun relative to the camera, the field of view of the camera, the aspect ratio of the window, and the direction of the light. All of those are core systems that have not changed meaningfully in half a decade, so I'd expect your research from past Q&A and tutorials should still apply. Can you show us how you've tried applying what you've learned from your research to solving this problem?

Comment: @DMGregory, Based on what I found on the Internet, I need to use Occlusion, but its use has changed almost nothing. I tried to play with light and camera, it looks like but not that. Then I thought it was with shaders, I tried a lot of shaders, but the shader in the picture is the most similar. Sorry if there are mistakes, English is not my first language

Comment: So specifically what you want is the fuzzy dark shadow beside and under the hammer at the back of the gun? It would be much better if your question stated that clearly. You should show us what ambient occlusion settings you tried to use to replicate this effect.

Comment: @DMGregory, after sitting and thinking a little more, I changed a little light, corrected the post effects and occlusion, and achieved the result as in MagicaVoxel. So thank you so much

Comment: Please post an Answer below walking through the steps you took.

Comment: Note that if you realize that "things have changed" across versions, you might want to specify 1) the question that is "too old" so we can refer to the same thing as you do and 2) the current version you're targeting in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

After sitting and thinking, I was able to achieve a result very similar to MagicaVoxel

In the first, I added two direct lights on both sides of the pistol, with these settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Secondly, I added post effects to the camera by changing the Volume Layer to Everything, as well as adding Anti-aliasing. Then I added a collider that had Color and Occlusion post effects.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As a result, we get this image.

I think it can still be edited and made more similar, but if you compare it with what it was, then the difference is obvious

[image]